# Django: How do I use UUIDField from django-extensions

Tags: django, django-models, django-extensions

How do I use the UUIDField in my model?

If i do

```
somefield = UUIDField
```

i get:

```
 UUIDField is not defined.
```

I do import uuid on top of my models file.

And i have django_extensions in installed apps...

Answer (score 23, accepted):

A good place to see how to use features of a Django app is in the app's tests.

Here are some example models from [django-extension's UUIDField tests](https://github.com/django-extensions/django-extensions/blob/master/django_extensions/tests/uuid_field.py) that demonstrate how to use the field:

```
from django.db import models
from django_extensions.db.fields import UUIDField


class TestModel_field(models.Model):
    a = models.IntegerField()
    uuid_field = UUIDField()


class TestModel_pk(models.Model):
    uuid_field = UUIDField(primary_key=True)
```

Without seeing the whole file, it's hard to tell what's going on. Make sure you import `UUIDField` from `django_extensions.db.fields` (like in the above example) and not Python's `uuid` module.